# Django: Calling delete() method on only() raise exception DoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

Let's say I have following model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   ...
```

When I am trying to call **delete()** method on **only()** like:

```
Student.object.filter(pk__in=[1, 5, 6]).only('id', 'name').delete()
```

I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist: Student matching query does not exist
```

**My question is:** can't we call delete() on only()?

**Note:** We are using only() on Django admin's get_queryset() method for better performance.

For your info, my admin looks like:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
       return qs.only('id', 'name', ...)
```

When we are trying to delete objects from Admin, we get this error.

Comment: What's the primary field for the model? Django is using Primary Key to interact with objects. You might not be including it into `only()`

Comment: DoesNotExists only gets raised in `Model.objects.get()`. So if you had written the same code with get earlier..has your server been restarted? if the problem perishes after restart as well..remove all *.pyc files. I have tried delete with only and it worked fine for me. Unfortunately cannot post it here for you.

Comment: @ThulasiRam, I think, you misunderstood the question. I was talking about [only() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Comment: @AndreyShipilov, there is no primary key in this model. So, by default *id* is the primary key. As I mentioned, *id* field is included in the *only* call.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you did mistake. Change

```
qs = super(ShipmentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
```

to

```
qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
```

Comment: by mistake wrote ShipmentAdmin here. In actual code, it is correct. Editing  the question.